# Java Generics: Explicitly check for raw type

Tags: java, generics, testng

I want to be able to set at runtime which type of item I want to instantiate. Below is a much simplified example of what I want to do, because the functionality is not the most relevant part of my question (and it already works correctly if you input a subclass of `Administrable`).

```
public class Role {
    private Class<? extends Administrable> admin;

    public Class<? extends Administrable> getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Class<? extends Administrable> admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public Administrable getAdministrable() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return admin.newInstance();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the test below fail with a `ClassCastException` (or any other `Exception`, really), but I was doubly surprised that my test code compiles, and runs without throwing any `RuntimeException`.

```
public class RoleTest {

    // this works already
    @Test
    public void testAdmin() {
        // Site is a subclass of Administrable
        Class<? extends Administrable> clazz = Site.class;
        role.setAdmin(clazz);
        assertEquals(clazz, role.getAdmin());
    }

    // this works already
    @Test
    public void testAdminNull() {
        role.setAdmin(null);
        assertNull(role.getAdmin());
    }

    // this test succeeds, i.e. it does not throw any exception
    @Test(expectedExceptions = RuntimeException.class) // using TestNG
    public void testAdminIllegal() {
        Class clazz = String.class;
        // I thought that this wouldn't even compile
        role.setAdmin(clazz);
        // But the strangest thing is that it seems to work at runtime, too !
        assertEquals(clazz, role.getAdmin());
    }
}
```

This means that I've got no explicit check in the setter for a raw type, and I really want one there. Is it possible to implement this check, and if so, how ? I've tried a few reflection techniques to get to see whether `clazz` is a `ParameterizedType`, with casting, etc, but nothing seems to work to satisfaction.

Comment: You are using a raw type. It would not compile with `Class<String> clazz = String.class;`. Your compiler should emit a warning though...

Comment: Generics provide *compile* time type safety. At runtime, all types are effectively raw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the raw type `Class`:

```
Class clazz = String.class;
// I thought that this wouldn't even compile
role.setAdmin(clazz);
```

Wont throw any exception, but your compiler will warn you that you use an unchecked type. If you actually gave a generic class `Class<?>`, it would not compile.

To check the type passed as parameter, change your method as follows:

```
public void setAdmin(Class<? extends Administrable> admin) {
    if (admin != null && !Administrable.class.isAssignableFrom(admin)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The parameter " + admin.getName() + " should be administrable.");
    }
    this.admin = admin;
}
```

Or if you want to make your test fail (without check), call a method from `Administrable` on an admin instance:

```
class Administrable {
    public void test(){}
}

public void testAdminIllegal() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class clazz = String.class;
    // I thought that this wouldn't even compile
    role.setAdmin(clazz);

    role.getAdministrable().test();
}
```